# My files from Downloads folder are gone

Tags: files, directory, delete

I was trying to make a bootable flashdrive with WIN7 using Yumi in my Ubuntu desktop. The process got stuck at 46% for over half an hour. I tried interrupting it, but it was not possible. So I unplugged the flashdrive. There were some error messages related to the flashdrive, but I kept using computer normally and turned it off after a couple minutes. Three hours later when I turned it on again my wallpaper has changed to a standard Ubuntu wallpaper and when I noticed all the files in Donwloads folder have disappeared (except for the content from a Popcorn Time unzipped file I have unzipped a week ago). I really have no clue of what could have happened. The system is booting normally, no additional problem has been noticed. I am using a 64gb SSD drive (Sandisk SDSSDP06) as boot drive.

Is there a way I can recover those files? Does the flashdrive issue have anything to do with the problem?

Cheers from Brazil

PS: the wallpaper picture was saved in Downloads folder.

PS2: Appart from the SSD drive, I also have 2 regular sata drives.

PS3: that was the result from typing the `mount` command on the terminal:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1979768k,nr_inodes=494942,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=404776k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=404776k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/andrednz/7699-63B4 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/andrednz/Escravo type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: If something actually deleted the files (and not just mounted another directory over it), STOP USING THAT COMPUTER! Every write access to the disk may overwrite the deleted data and make recovery impossible. You may [edit] your question and add the output of the `mount` command to list all mountpoints.

Comment: Hello, @ByteCommander. I did what you asked me to. But I have to tell you that my expertise on linux is not deep enough to comprehend any of those lines...

Comment: I ran a live session of Lubuntu from a flashdrive, executed Photorec, recovered a couple of JPG files as smaller PNG versions, but none of those pictures belonged to the folder Downloads in the SSD drive...

Comment: The output tells me which devices and directories are mounted as what. Most of them are virtual anyway, but some are not. However, there is nothing overriding any directory in your home folder, so your Downloads folder was definitely erased and not just hidden behind a mount point. Then you need a data recovery specialist or at least an answer from one here on the site... Sorry but I am not one. Good luck.

Comment: Guess I'll keep watching the SSD drive for possible physical problems and change the download folder option in my browser to a folder in one of my other two drives. 

Thank you for your prompt help, @ByteCommander! Um abraço!